# Migrating an application using a custom API logging system

Tags: .net, logging, service, visual-basic-6, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm turning a VB6 application into a VB.NET (using a migration tool). This software relies on a custom DLL which handles logging. This DLL logs to flat files and optionnaly in a GUI component.

Also this application will become a Windows service. Since I'll have to rewrite parts of the code, I wonder what benefits I would got switching to the .NET `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` component. I think that keeping a custom logging system would be fine, but am I missing something?

Note: the DLL is .NET COM-Visible, and can be used from a .NET piece of software.

Comment: This would be something to research and find out which solution best suits your needs.   A quick google search will turn up a number of different options for logging frameworks for .NET  - https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+logging+framework

Comment: Thanks @ben-cottrell. Actually I asked about benefits using a third-party like `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` rather than keeping/using a home-made solution. I'm more looking for documentation looking like _Why you should avoid to log by yourself_ or something.